# BigSheets - java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

Tags: ibm-cloud, biginsights

I'm unable to browse data with BigSheets on BigInsights on Cloud.  When I select a file and change the Reader type, I receive the exception (see screenshot, below).

I was previously able to browse data ok.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to restart the BigX services in the Ambari console.

Answer (score 0):

Have you logged into BigSheets as a biadmin user ? I think there is some permission issue since you are trying to access the file created by biadmin (/user/biadmin).

One option to confirm is, login to bigsheets as biadmin and try the same.

Comment: Hi Nisanth - yes, I was logged in as biadmin.

Comment: Are you facing the error for other files - Like you can create a file under /tmp and give full permission and check it. You may need to check the bigsheets logs for more details of the error

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing impersonation of biadmin user and try your scenario.

Login to Ambari UI, then go to HDFS --> Config --> Advanced --> Custom core-site

Update or Add the property

hadoop.proxyuser.biadmin.groups=*
hadoop.proxyuser.biadmin.hosts=*